# Markdown output

Tags: r, output, markdown

I can't create output of R code in markdown. It looks like it doesn't execute it. I create a new markdown document, choose type "HTML". If I type

````
```{r}
log(2)
```
````

I'll get a string with log(2) after knittig but this will not produce the output. It won't give me 0.6931472 beneath it.
Currently I have following:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

other attached packages:

```
[1] knitr_1.15.1   markdown_0.7.7
```

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

```
 [1] backports_1.0.5 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.2    
 [6] yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.9     stringi_1.1.2   rmarkdown_1.3   stringr_1.2.0  
[11] digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10
```

Comment: How are you attempting to "run" this document? Is this in R Studio?

Comment: is there any global option that has set the `eval=FALSE`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I spent the whole day trying to understand what's going on. After I posted this I accidentally come to a solution - in "global options" under the "sweave" it somehow changed "knitr" (which was default) to "sweave". Because I absolutely new to this it took me time to understand the problem. I hope this solution will help somebody.